# I have a formlayout error when running a Blazor website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, blazor, circuit

I updated visual studio 19 and before that my site ran exactly how i intended it. Now i am getting an error when i load the home page but then breaks before it can finish loading it. I have provided the error code below. I also would let you know that i have seen this post ( [How to turn on CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514541/how-to-turn-on-circuitoptions-detailederrors) ) and tried it all but it hasn't worked.

```
Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 
'http://fakesite.com/_blazor'.

Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this 
circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions in 
'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'

Information: Connection disconnected.
```

new error after implementing Hanks solution

```
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'FormLayout' in 'window.DxBlazor'.
Error: Could not find 'FormLayout' in 'window.DxBlazor'.
    at http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:27768
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at d (http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:27729)
    at http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:28342
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:28316)
    at http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:19148
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.invokeClientMethod (http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:19119)
    at e.processIncomingData (http://fakesite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:17165)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeBase.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, IEnumerable`1 args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

this is the CreateWebHostBuilder method

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")
     .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
     .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Can you post your `CreateWebHostBuilder` method code?

Comment: Hey @MindSwipe , i have added the method to my post

Comment: Are you using the latest version .NET Core 3.0 Preview 8? The latest Visual Studio 2019 update was afaik for the Preview 8. Could be a .NET Core versioning problem.

Comment: Hey @PascalR. , i am using the latest version .NET Core 3.0 Preview 8.

Comment: What you have posted is OK, but what about the hosting?  Are WebSockets enabled? How do you deploy (Self-contained or not?)

Comment: Ok, it now looks like a problem with hosting or publishing. Do you have (and use) an option like "Remove additional files at destination" ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No i do not have an option like that

Comment: Well, inform us about how you deploy to what host.

Comment: You seem to use DevExpress for Blazor. Have you updated the DevExpress NuGet package to the latest version preview 8? Are there four files in `wwwroot/lib/dx-blazor`?

Comment: Hey @HenkHolterman i publish it to IIS on a local Microsoft sever

Comment: Hey @PascalR. yes i am using DevExpress and i have the latest preview 8 v0.2.0. i also have all the necessary files as to what there github describes.

Comment: Another user seems to have had the same problem in this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609202/error-after-updating-visual-studio-2019-preview He solved it by deleting his browser cache / cookies. Does that work for you?

Comment: @PascalR. i do not believe his problem is the same as mine, but i tried it anyway and to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update to visual studios there was updares to all my NuGet packages too. This included the DevExpress for Blazor NuGet package and with that update they changed the link to the dx-blazor.js and dx-blazor.css files that your supposed to put I your layout’s HEAD section.

From:

```
<link href="lib/dx-blazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/dx-blazor.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<link href="lib/dx-blazor/dx-blazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/dx-blazor/dx-blazor.js"></script>
```

Hope this maybe helps others in my situation or in a situation similar to mine.

Answer (score 5):

Start by taking the advice literally.

In Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services
  .AddServerSideBlazor()
  .AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
```

and then post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is issue is related to client scripts. If you see "window.DxBlazor" in the message, this means that you need to look for the cause in the client scripts. Please make sure that you have the latest up-to-date DevExpress scripts included in your project.
See the 6th item of the [How to create a new project](https://github.com/devexpress/blazor#how-to-create-a-new-project) paragraph.