# Error after updating visual studio 2019 preview

Tags: blazor

Getting an error in IE console while loading Blazor application after updating Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1 to Preview 2

> Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: iconRef is not defined
>   ReferenceError: iconRef is not defined

Answer (score 0):

When deleting all the browsing data like cookies, cache extra the issue is resolved.