# How to turn on CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors per user/session/connection?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

This question [How to turn on CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57514541/3786) shows how to turn on `DetailsErrors` but this is called once when the server starts up.

I would like to be able to switch `DetailedErrors` for a specific circuit so I can debug issues for a specific user without having it affect the whole system.

Is this possible?